# i += 1 TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, increment, typeerror

can someone tell why this isnt working?

i give some arguments from file 1 to a function in file 2 (myfile.py -i inpufile -n 3 etc). -n 3 means create 3 times something like CS_TH, CS_Z4 etc. and append it to a list (in File 2 cs_id = []).

*File1..snip..*

```
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
        func.usage()
        sys.exit()
    elif opt in '-d':
        global _debug
        _debug = 1
    elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
        global ifile
        ifile = arg
    elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
        global ofile
        ofile = arg
    elif opt in ("-n", "--NumberOfInstances"):
        global instances
        instances = arg

func.unzip(ifile, instances)
```

*File 2 .. snip ..*

```
def unzip(ifile, instances,):
    global cs_id
    newinstance = ifile
    nos = instances
    i = 0
    cs_id = []
    for i in nos:
        cs_id.append('CS_' + id_generator())
        i += 1
    print ', '.join(cs_id)
```

i got this error

```
i += 1
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I found some information about integer increment in the net, but i dont understand whats the problem here. There is a list cs_id = [] that have to be filled as much as argument -n is set (e.g -n 3).

I hope i explain it the right way.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same variable name for the loop elements, so inside the loop `i` is a String and not the counter declared above it. Then, being a String and knowing that python doesn't like you concatenating things that aren't of the same type, you trigger the TypeError

If you want to work with the argument as an integer, you should convert it to one with [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#int), and for converting an int to a string, use [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#str) and of course use different variable names :)

Answer (score 0):

`for i in nos` assigns `i` a string value. You have further (mistakenly) used the count variable `i`, expecting it to be still an `int`, which it's not. Hence the problem. Try this instead:

```
for no in nos:
```

Answer (score 0):

You made 2 mistakes:

- using the same variable `i` for looping your variable `nos` and counting its length
- trying to concatenate a string (the current element of `nos`) and your loop counter

Just replace `for i in nos:` by `for _ in nos:` as it is a silent variable in your case. This way, you will loop on `nos` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is likely here:

```
elif opt in ("-n", "--NumberOfInstances"):
    global instances
    instances = arg
```

Anything that comes from the command line is a string, so `arg` is a string.  You probably want to convert it to an integer with int():

```
instances = int(arg)
```

And then you need to fix your loop:

```
def unzip(ifile, instances,):
    global cs_id
    newinstance = ifile
    cs_id = []
    for i in xrange(instances):
        cs_id.append('CS_' + id_generator())
    print ', '.join(cs_id)
```

If you're using Python 3, use `range()` instead of `xrange()`.

Comment: Thx this help me much guys! Now it works fine. Didn´t about the fact, that cmd arguments are strings etc.

Comment: Yeah, some languages allow math on strings (I believe Perl allows this), but Python doesn't.  So you have to convert it first.  Glad I could help!